# Sencha Chart not showing in view

Tags: extjs, charts

At the top of my view, I have defined the following variable:

```
      var chartq = new Ext.chart.Chart({
      renderTo : Ext.getBody(), 
      xtype: 'chart',
      animate: true,
        width : 400,
        height : 300,
        store: {
            fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'metric one',
                'data1': 10,
                'data2': 12,
                'data3': 14,
                'data4': 8,
                'data5': 13
            }, {
                'name': 'metric two',
                'data1': 7,
                'data2': 8,
                'data3': 16,
                'data4': 10,
                'data5': 3
            }, {
                'name': 'metric three',
                'data1': 5,
                'data2': 2,
                'data3': 14,
                'data4': 12,
                'data5': 7
            }, {
                'name': 'metric four',
                'data1': 2,
                'data2': 14,
                'data3': 6,
                'data4': 1,
                'data5': 23
            }, {
                'name': 'metric five',
                'data1': 27,
                'data2': 38,
                'data3': 36,
                'data4': 13,
                'data5': 33
            }]
        },
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric',
            position: 'left',
            title: {
                text: 'Sample Values',
                fontSize: 15
            },
            fields: 'data1'
        }, {
            type: 'category',
            position: 'bottom',
            title: {
                text: 'Sample Values',
                fontSize: 15
            },
            fields: 'name'
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            xField: 'name',
            yField: 'data1',
            style: {
                fill: 'blue'
            }
        }]
    });


Ext.define('axis3.view.Chart', {

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
    alias: 'widget.chartview',
    getSlideLeftTransition: function () {
        return { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' };
    },

    getSlideRightTransition: function () {
        return { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' };
    },
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        items: [{
                    xtype : 'label',
                    html : 'Some label.'
                        },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    items:chartq  //Ext.chart.Chart 
              },
              {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'bottom',
                },
                {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Axis First Stats App',
            docked: 'top',


            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Log Off',
                    itemId: 'logOffButton',
                    align: 'right'
                },
                 {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Back',
                    itemId: 'backButton',
                    align: 'left'
                },

            ],

        }],
        html: [
                    '<div id="localuid">Signed in Uid: <span>'+localStorage.uid+'</span></div>'
                ].join(""),

        listeners: [{
            delegate: '#logOffButton',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: 'onLogOffButtonTap'
        },{
            delegate: '#backButton',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: 'onBacktButtonTap'
        }]
    },
    onLogOffButtonTap: function () {
        localStorage.clear();
        window.location.reload();
    },
    onBackButtonTap: function () {

    Ext.create('axis3.view.Main',{});
     Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem('mainview', this.getSlideRightTransition());
    },

});
```

The view becomes active as expected when a button in the toolbar is pressed. But, the chart is not visible. No errors are shown in console log. I have tried adding the variable to the config and to the 'items', but the chart still does not show. No errors in console.log

The container for the chart is being created in the browser as expected - just no graph appearing

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: It's not clear from your shown code exactly how your view is using that chart.  Can you create a jsfiddle to demo this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charts need a width and height before they'll render properly. I added a static width and height to your `chartq` definition and it appeared as I would expect:

```
    var chartq = new Ext.chart.Chart({
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        store: {...
```

Comment: Thanks @sherb. I have added the full code that I am using. Your suggestion was added, but I think there is something else I am missing

Comment: @JezD, two questions: (1) I see the declaration for `chartButton`, but where is the handler for that button, and (2) where is the reference to `chartq`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The button is actually superfluous for this view. It was copied from another. I need the chart to be there when the view is active. I have tried referencing chartq in various places, including the html: and config->items, but to no avail.

Comment: Understood; I'm guessing that your code example is part of a much larger program and you're trying to pare it down. I dropped your original `chartq` declaration (with width and height) into a `Viewport` and it rendered fine, so the problem is in the container and not the chart. I'm certain that you can only attach `DomHelper` objects to `html`, so that might be the place to start.

Comment: Thanks. I have just checked it on iPad and it seems fine there. So, it's only the desktop that doesn't like it.